# Java Counting the number of alphabets

Tags: java, algorithm, count, alphabet

During making programs about counting the number of alphabets each(e.g input-abc/output- a:1, b:1, c:1, d:0, ... , z:0)I have a problem. I don't know why the if clauses does not work...
Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Prac05 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = sc.nextLine();
        String[] b = a.split("");


        if (a.length() <= 100) {
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; j++) {
                    if(b[i].equals((char) j)) {
                        System.out.println("1");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am supposed to print "1", however since if-clauses does not true, nothing does output...

Comment: `b[i]` is a `String` and `(char) j` is boxed to a `Character`. String and Character can never be equal.

Comment: You should be able to do this with one loop and one if statement using just `a` unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a `String` object to a `Character` object, which do not equal each other because of their different types.

An easy solution, which will also result in more efficient and more elegant code is to use [String.charAt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)), rather than splitting the original string to a lot of small `String` objects, and iterate from `0` to `a.length` for each character in the string.